# Преобразование строки в массив с последующим обращением

Tags: php, массивы, json

Получаем json-массив как строку

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Если делаем так

```
$result = (array)curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result; //вывод - {"cost": "0.73"}
```

то в итоге получаем просто массив где нулевой элемент равен `{"cost": "0.73"}`.
Собственно мне надо вытащить число, а оно может быть любой длины.
Как можно строку преобразовать в массив ключ-значение? Я просто с регулярными не дружу(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); 
$cost = $result->cost;
```

Comment: итишкинаитишка...совсем про декодер забыл(( недавно же в jquey юзал...спасибо)